# How to force run all RSpec specs ignoring :focus tag

Tags: rspec, rspec2

Given the following RSpec configuration (v2.12.0):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
 config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true
 config.filter_run :focus => true
 config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
end
```

Sometimes people forget to remove the `:focus` tag from specs and in a continuous integration environment where we want all specs to be run, only the specs with the leftover `:focus` tag get run.

I've tried:

```
rspec --tag ~focus
```

... which runs all specs excluding those tagged with :focus

Is there a way to force run **ALL** specs ignoring any tags using rspec's command line options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could remove the lines:

```
 config.filter_run :focus => true
 config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true
```

and tell users to run focused tests with `rspec --tag focus`. That way the CI will always run the full test suite.

You might consider checking the environment in the configuration block and including/excluding the `filter_run` setting appropriately.

Another thought: if you are using git, set a pre-commit hook to prevent specs with `:focus` from creeping into the code base in the first place.

Comment: Using environment variables seem like a sensible solution, e.g.:
`config.filter_run :focus => true unless ENV['CI']`

Comment: @prashantrajan That wouldn't work for me. Our Codeship servers run the tests before deploying to CI.  As expected, they run tests in ENV['TEST']

Answer (score 13):

I just added this to a project:

```
config.before :focused => true do
  fail "Hey dummy, don't commit focused specs." if ENV['FORBID_FOCUSED_SPECS']
end
```

And in the script that our continuous integration server runs:

```
export FORBID_FOCUSED_SPECS=true
```

Comment: I like this since, unlike relying on Rails.env.ci?, it can be used by our Codeship test runs which use test environment.

Comment: I like this idea, but I'd prefer to force users to opt into this behavior (i.e. `ENV['ALLOW_FOCUSED_SPECS']`). That way the default behavior is to fail if there are any focused specs.

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to automatically fail on our continuous integration server when focus was set. This was rewritten based on [code](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1300#issuecomment-72933600) from myronmarston to work correctly with rspec-rails 3.2.0:

```
  config.before(:example, :focus) do
    fail 'This example was committed with `:focus` and should not have been'
  end if ENV['CI']
```

Answer (score 5):

Try: `rspec --tag focus --tag ~focus`

Comment: At first glance this looks perfect, but with `filter_run` this has the same effect as `rspec --tag ~focus`:- focused specs are excluded.